# CSS background-size: cover; works badly

Tags: html, css, cover, background-size

I have a `#div` element with the following CSS styles:

```
width: 413px;
height: 140px;
background-image: url("URL-TO-IMAGE");
background-color: #53A7E7;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

And the result is the following:

[image: banner]

As you can see in the left and bottom part of the element there are two blue lines (the color corresponds to the code `#53A7E7`).

If I delete the style `background-size: cover;` both lines disappear and the image covers the entire surface of the element.

Any idea how to fix this?

The original image has the dimensions 1779x683 pixels, but I want it to be fixed for any image size.

```css
#div {
    width: 413px;
    height: 140px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvWWN.png");
    background-color: #53A7E7;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: please post your code in the snippet.

Comment: Please post your HTML that corresponds with this. "works badly" isn't a very good description of the problem.

Comment: i had a similar problem back then, i don't think it was the best solution but it worked for me, what i did was to set the width and height a to be a bit more bigger than the viewport height/width, i.e. `width:115vw; heigth:=110vh;`

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `background-color` and `background-size: cover` at the same time because the image will be on top of the color. If you need a color around your `background-size` that is cover, just add `border`. The `background-size: cover` is working corectly. In your example I suppose you need `display: inline-block`.

```css
#div {
    width: 413px;
    height: 140px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvWWN.png");
    border: 10px solid #53A7E7;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: not sure how this is anwering the question ... probably I completely missed the question but it seems that the lines are unwanted and this is a simple rendering issue